# Commit a particular file in SVN using SVNKit

Tags: svn, commit, svnkit

How to commit a particular file instead of a whole directory in SVN using SVNKit?

Code to commit whole dir:

```
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager((String) session.getAttribute("USERNAME"), (String) session.getAttribute("PASSWORD"));
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

        SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(null,repository.getAuthenticationManager());
        SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient();
        updateClient.doUpdate(wcDir, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false);
        ourClientManager.getWCClient().doInfo(wcDir, SVNRevision.HEAD);
        SVNCommitInfo s1=ourClientManager.getCommitClient().doCommit(new File[] {wcDir}, true, "From Code", svnProperties.getRegularProperties(), null, true, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
```

Comment: Please post the code you are currently using to commit a whole directory.

Answer (score 8):

If you use SVNKit as a library, use this code:

```
final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {
    final SvnCommit commit = svnOperationFactory.createCommit();
    commit.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(file));
    commit.setCommitMessage("Commit message");
    final SVNCommitInfo commitInfo = commit.run();
} finally {
    svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

If you use SVNKit as command line instrument, run:

```
$ jsvn commit path/to/file
```

**Update:**
Here's the code for 1.3.x

```
final SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
try {
    final SVNCommitClient commitClient = clientManager.getCommitClient();
    final SVNCommitInfo commitInfo = commitClient.doCommit(new File[]{file}, false, "Commit message", null, null, false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
} finally {
    clientManager.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I am using svnkit 1.3.5 jar file. when used above code,it shows me error.

Comment: This code is for SVNKit 1.7.x. For 1.3.x use SVNClientManager to create SVNCommitClient and call SVNCommitClient#doCommit of the file you want to commit.

Comment: I have pasted my code for committing the whole directory. but i couldn't commit a specific file.

Comment: What happens if you replace wcDir with file to commit?