# SVN commit with Gradle

Tags: svn, gradle

How do I commit a single file to an SVN 1.7 repository using Gradle?

I'd like to use Jenkins to provide the credentials, the commit message, and the path to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515110/commit-a-particular-file-in-svn-using-svnkit#answer-15523434), this is the Gradle task that commits a single file using [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/).

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath "org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:1.7.11"}
}

import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.*
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.*

task svnCommitFile(){
    description = "Commits a single file to an SVN repository"
    doLast{
        if (!project.hasProperty("commitMsg")){
          ext.commitMsg = "None"
        }
        SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory()
        def authentication = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(svnUser, svnPassword)
        svnOperationFactory.setAuthenticationManager(authentication)
        try {
            SvnCommit commit = svnOperationFactory.createCommit()
            commit.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(new File(fileToCommit)))
            commit.setCommitMessage(commitMsg)
            SVNCommitInfo commitInfo = commit.run()
            println "Commit info: " + commitInfo
            println "Commit message: " + commitMsg
        } finally{
            svnOperationFactory.dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with `gradle svnCommitFile -PfileToCommit="path/to/file" -PcommitMsg="My message" -PsvnUser="me" -PsvnPassword="verySecret"`

---

If this commit is done with Jenkins after every commit to the project, you will get in an infinite build loop, because a commit causes a build which causes a commit which causes a build...

Therefore Jenkins should ignore its own commits: In your project's build configuration go to `Source Code Management --> Subversion --> Advanced` and add `jenkins` (or however you call your automated committer) to the `Excluded Users`.

Comment: Does this take care of adding the file to SVN first, if need be, or would additional code be required ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's added to SVN first, no additional code required.

Comment: How I may hide the password over here?

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi: You can store the password in an environment variable or give [Jenkins' Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) a try.